# Memory allocation for classes in java

Tags: java, class, memory-management, trie

This is a working java code which is used for implementing trie data structure.

```
class TrieNode {
TrieNode[] arr;
boolean isEnd;
// Initialize your data structure here.
public TrieNode() {
    this.arr = new TrieNode[26];
}
```

What I don't understand is how the memory allocation works with

```
TrieNode[] arr;
```

code. If it were something like this

```
class TrieNode {
    int[] arr;
    boolean isEnd;
    // Initialize your data structure here.
    public TrieNode() {
        this.arr = new int[26];
    }
```

I know that this allocates memory for 26 integers. 
It's better if you can explain how the memory allocation works for first code.
(In compiler's perspective)

EDIT : Sorry if my question is unclear.What im asking is we create array with 26 elements in

```
new TrieNode[26];
```

How much memory is allocated?

Comment: In java all you have references and actual object resides in memory. References refer to the objects in heap. Now when you have `new TrieNode[26]`, you have 26 references of type `TrieNode` (in contigous memory) but actual objects will reside in heap which need not be contigous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your first code, When you create object of TriNode like

```
TriNode t = new TriNode();
```

JVM will allocate memory to store  26 references for arr  elements and 1 reference for isEnd field. To store references , JVM uses 32 bits for a 32 bit JVM and 64 bits for a 64 bit JVM.
When you create array

```
new TrieNode[26];
```

It will allocate 26*(64bit/32bit)+1 boolean because it doesn't create TrieNode objects instead it creates array of references to store TriNode objects which are not created yet. So when you initialise array elements like

```
arr[0] = new TrieNode();
```

Then it will allocate memmory for TrieNode() object and arr[0] will point this object.

> So conclusion is JVM will not allocate memory for  26 Trinode objects
>   instead it will allocate memory for their references.

Answer (score 0):

Up until you do no call `new` no memory allocation is done.

So `TrieNode[] arr;`  act as a future reference.
Only when you call the constructor, Java will allocate the memory and set the reference inside `arr`.

Links:

- https://dzone.com/articles/what-does-java-array-look
- [Arrays in Java and how they are stored in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564423/arrays-in-java-and-how-they-are-stored-in-memory)

Comment: How much memory is allocated for TrieNode[] arr; ? because we haven't specified it. Sorry I'm new to programming.

Comment: I don't konw the details but it depends of your JVM. If you run a 32-bits JVM you will get a 32bits per reference if you have a a 64-bits JVM you can get up to 64bits reference. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721568/size-of-reference-of-an-class-in-java

Comment: No it's not what I'm asking :( I have edited the question